# Building a JSON API in Rails 4

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, json

How to build the JSON API for add the post. I am creating the Rails application and connect it with iphone application by using the JSON API. User can add the Blog/Post from application so how I can add the blog data like title, text and image in rails database(using the new method).

Answer (score 0):

You can have your controllers return JSON by doing something like:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: Project.all }
        end
    end

    def show
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: Project.where(name: params[:name])}
        end
    end
end
```

This is essentially turning rails into a JSON API. Make sure to add your model attributes to the Active::Model::serializers

```
class ProjectSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :imgUrl, :deployUrl
end
```

Comment: That's perfect but it's for showing the list of and the details of single post. want to take data from iphone application and add the new post.

Comment: I think it's because you are doing Patient.new and not saving it. You would need to do @patient.save! after.

Comment: It save the Patient but all the fields are empty only ID of post is created.

Comment: Try replacing .new with .create

Comment: It show me {"id":5,"created_at":"2015-02-02T19:29:08.951Z","name":null,"hospitaladmin_id":null,"gender":null,"date_of_birth":null,"contact_no":null,"billing_id":null,"discharge_status":null,"physician":null,"updated_at":"2015-02-02T19:29:08.951Z"} when I hit  www.localhost:3000/api/addpatient.json?name=test&gender=male&date_of_birth=10/02/2010&contact_no=58475896&billing_id=25&physician=48 url

Comment: Ooooh cause you're sending in params[:I'd] and not patient_params

Comment: @patient = Patient.create(patient_params)

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
   def patient
   @patients = Patient.all
   respond_with(@patients)
 end
def disease
 @diseasecode = Diseasecode.all
 respond_with(@diseasecode)
end
def addpatient
  @patient = Patient.new(params[:id])
  flash[:notice] = 'Patient was successfully created.' if @patient.save
  respond_with(@patient)
end    
def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit(:name, :gender, :date_of_birth, :contact_no, :billing_id, :physician)
end
end
```

I am getting still problem     def addpatient   method   is  never add the post if I hit the url               www.localhost:3000/api/addpatient.json?name=test&gender=male&date_of_birth=10/02/2010&contact_no=58475896&billing_id=25&physician=48